# Menu de RStudio en Español

Tags: rstudio, idioma

Quisiera cambiar el idioma de los menues de Rstudio de Ingles a Español pero no he podido. Alguna pista? Gracias

Comment: En la consola tipea `Sys.getlocale()` eso deberia cambiarlo.

Comment: Rstudio actualmente no es localizable, por lo que la interfaz solo podrá verse en inglés.

Comment: Muchas gracias.